# Do I have to build fat jar for my library?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jar

Currently, I am making a library and try to import it to our project.
The library contains libraries such as [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed).

The code below is the `build.gradle.kts` of the library.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

val exposedVersion: String by project
dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation(kotlin("test"))
    implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))

    implementation(kotlin("script-runtime"))
    implementation(kotlin("script-util"))
    implementation(kotlin("scripting-jsr223"))
    implementation("org.slf4j", "slf4j-api", "1.7.30")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:$exposedVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:$exposedVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:$exposedVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-java-time:$exposedVersion")
}
```

However, when JAR is built and added to the project, it throws an error(NoClassDefFoundError) that it cannot find classes referenced by JAR such as Exposed.

Because of the above error, like the code below, I have to add all the libraries I added from the library back to the project.

```
val exposedVersion: String by project
dependencies {
    // spring
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    
    /** other dependencies */
    // Dependencies for `my library jar`
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
    implementation(kotlin("script-runtime"))
    implementation(kotlin("scripting-jsr223"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:$exposedVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:$exposedVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:$exposedVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-java-time:$exposedVersion")

}
```

The `build.gradle.kts` I want is as follows.

```
val exposedVersion: String by project
dependencies {
    // spring
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    
    /** other dependencies */
    // Dependencies for `my library jar`
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
}
```

How can I do what I want? Do I have to make fat jar?

Comment: How are you "adding the jar to the project"—with the `fileTree`? Why are you not making it a proper dependency like the others you know how to use?

Comment: After seeing what `Exposed` did, I tried to change all `implements` of build.krs in the library to `api`, but the problem was not solved. Is there any other way to build jar?

Is it a problem to add as `fileTree`? Does it solve the problem if I use maven repository?

Comment: Adding as `fileTree` is a problem, because then Gradle doesn't understand that your library needs those other jars. Instead, you should be saying `implementation("my:library:1.2.3")`. You may need to publish this library to a Maven-compatible repository to do this (either OSSRH or a private one).

Answer (score -2):

I see you are using spring boot so the most straightforward way would be to use [Spring Boot Gradle Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) and when it is configured in your project you run task `bootJar` and a fat spring boot jar will be created.

Comment: But the library does not have  spring dependency and main class. this jar is not executable.